# How to get a facebook url like www.facebook.com/mysite

Tags: facebook, url

I have seen this everywhere, on television and now on bottles of Evian water.  they have their Facebook page as [www.facebook.com/evianUK](http://www.facebook.com/evianUK)

I have created a company Facebook page for a website I'm building and I want to have the website name as part of the url.

I know how to do mod rewrite but obviously i can't on here.

Is there a setting i need to change or how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here for all information about vanity names: [Usernames for Facebook Pages](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=900)

Pretty much: get 25 fans, log in as the administrator, visit [facebook.com/username](http://www.facebook.com/username).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a page "alias" (or nickname, I don't remember exactly how does they call it..).
You also need a minimum number of fans in order to do this.

**EDIT:** You need 25 fans at the moment, in order to get that..

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work: [How to create a facebook subdomain](http://butyoureagirl.com/2591/how-to-create-a-subdomain-to-your-facebook-page/).
Btw: You need a minimum number of fans in order to create a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

log in to facebook and go to here: https://www.facebook.com/username/